# If else causes unexpected token in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think I've wrapped brackets properly but I am still getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 22: Unexpected token if

if(this.state.isEditing) {
^
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ley7uac/12/)

**Relevant code**

```
...
renderItem(){
   return (
       if(this.state.isEditing) {
           <input type="text" />
           <button>Save</button>
       } else {
           this.state.items.map((item, i) => 
               <li key={i}>
                   {item}&nbsp;
                   <button>Edit</button>
                   <button onClick={this.dlt_item.bind(this, i)}>Delete</button>
               </li>
           )
       }
   )
},
...
```

Comment: @AndrewL. because it's react?

Comment: what I want is really simple, if the user click edit show the input text

Comment: @AndrewL. where? I did not see it. Click the jsfiddle link and u shall see the error.

Comment: @AndrewL. open this link http://jsfiddle.net/3Ley7uac/12/ and see the error in the console.

Comment: @torazaburo That's literally the topic of the question

Comment: @torazaburo Is this a dumbest-question-of- the-day competition now? Seems to be a tie at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an `if-else` statement in a `return` function. Also You can also make use of `ternary operators` instead of `if-else`. Also I would recommend you do have a go at some of the basic react tutorials that will get you basics clear on some of the important syntax's

Also React clearly tells you what the error is. Just search for that error and you can easily find your problem. Also you should first try to see where exacty the error points at and then debug with a proper method. Hope this helps and you can debug the rest of the errors on your own.

Do it this way

```
renderItem(){
   var renderIt = null;
   if(this.state.isEditing){
    renderIt =  <div><input type="text" />
                <button>Save</button></div>
   }else{
      renderIt = this.state.items.map((item,i)=> <li key={i}>{item}
   &nbsp;
   <button>Edit</button>
   <button onClick={this.dlt_item.bind(this,i)}>Delete</button>
   </li>
   )
   }
   return (
   <div>{renderIt}</div>


   )
   },
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ley7uac/13/)

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
   return {
     items:[1,2,3],
     isEditing:false
   }
   },
   dlt_item(key){
   var newItems = this.state.items.filter((item,i)=> i !== key)
   this.setState({items:newItems})
   },
   edit_handler(){
   this.setState({isEditing:true})
   },
   isEditing_html(){
    return(
     <div>
     <input type="text" />
     <button>Save</button>
     </div>
     )
   },
   renderItem(){

   return(

      this.state.items.map(function(item,i) {

       var temp = null;
       if(this.state.isEditing){
   temp = this.isEditing_html()
   }else{
   temp = <div><button>Edit</button>
   <button onClick={this.dlt_item.bind(this,i)}>Delete</button></div>
   }
      return (<li key={i}>{item}
   &nbsp;
   {temp}
   </li>

   )
   }.bind(this)
   )
   )
   },
   render(){
      return(
      <ul>
        {this.renderItem()}
      </ul>
      )
   }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1erw4fba/2/)**

Comment: *You cannot have an if-else statement in a return function* Why not? Some other languages let you do this. What's the principle in JS syntax that prevents me from doing this?

Comment: What if I want to put it inside every li? I have error here too http://jsfiddle.net/3ndkqsj6/

Comment: @torazaburo React is based on JSX that doesnt allow you to have if-else statement in return. Code in return is supposed to be pure JSX

Comment: @JessieCampbell as the error says, you must wrap your component in a single element you cannot have more than one JSX elements. Wrap your content in a div

Comment: @JessieCampbell You needed to wrap your buttons in a div like this one see
http://jsfiddle.net/1erw4fba/1/ Also you can see the if else statements render as they are. use them outside of return

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri can u point me out here http://jsfiddle.net/3ondt6fL/ what is my problem?

Comment: @torazaburo using a ternary operator is a terrible pattern for React.

Comment: @JessieCampbell http://jsfiddle.net/1erw4fba/3/ works. Wrap  `<button>Edit</button>
   <button onClick={this.dlt_item.bind(this,i)}>Delete</button>` in a div. Call functtion ` isEditing_html() `with `this.isEditing_html()` and also use if-else correctly

Comment: I know it will become like this. I told you that you can't use if-else in the return statement. have the look at this fiddle and see how I handled it. Try and experiment with things  jsfiddle.net/1erw4fba/3

Comment: Ok I got it. http://jsfiddle.net/1erw4fba/4/ In here, when you click delete, why the input text of isEditing:false appear?

Comment: You should try and debug the logic of your code. Have a look at the flow and check for the properties. This is how you will get to know the language.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're doing an `if` statement inside a `return` block. Try a format like this:

```
renderItem() {
  if(this.state.isEditing) {
    return (
      <div>Editing</div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>Default</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see how a ternary would make this any better.

Comment: **Spoiler alert**: It wouldn't. It would make it less readable.